# Cocos2d scene has weird positioning

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm not quiet sure I understand the positioning in my cocos2d scene.
I'm putting something in the middle of the scene ( or so I think ) by using

```
winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
_leftScrollLayer.position = ccp (winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
```

However when this loads, the layer is loaded off screen... So then I try the position (0,0), which I assume is the bottom left corner of the screen. This then loads the layer to the top right of the screen...

Not sure if I'm missing anything, I've been playing around with the scene's anchorPoint and position, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Did you change the layer's or layer's parent position or anchorPoint?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have to set the [anchorPoint](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#ac24fc742eb11ee96207052639224434c). Try setting it to the center of your node:

```
_leftScrollLayer.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
```

Comment: to my understanding, anchorPoint 0.5,0.5 means the middle of the layer? that means it should be centered if i set the position to winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2. This results in a blank screen again :(